# Laravel 8 vue 2 "npm run watch" giving `mix watch` error. Can anyone help please?

Tags: npm

node v 14.16.0

npm v 6.14.11

> @ watch E:\xampp\htdocs
> mix watch

E:\xampp\htdocs\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:181
throw new TypeError(
^
TypeError: The 'compilation' argument must be an instance of Compilation
at Function.getCompilationHooks (E:\xampp\htdocs\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:181:10)
at E:\xampp\htdocs\node_modules\vue-loader\lib\plugin-webpack5.js:36:70
at Hook.eval [as call] (eval at create (E:\XAMPP\htdocs\node_modules\tapable\lib\HookCodeFactory.js:19:10), :206:1)
at Hook.CALL_DELEGATE [as _call] (E:\XAMPP\htdocs\node_modules\tapable\lib\Hook.js:14:14)
at Compiler.newCompilation (E:\XAMPP\htdocs\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compiler.js:1017:26)
at E:\XAMPP\htdocs\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compiler.js:1059:29
at Hook.eval [as callAsync] (eval at create (E:\XAMPP\htdocs\node_modules\tapable\lib\HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), :22:1)
at Hook.CALL_ASYNC_DELEGATE [as _callAsync] (E:\XAMPP\htdocs\node_modules\tapable\lib\Hook.js:18:14)
at Compiler.compile (E:\XAMPP\htdocs\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compiler.js:1054:28)
at E:\XAMPP\htdocs\node_modules\webpack\lib\Watching.js:134:19
at Hook.eval [as callAsync] (eval at create (E:\XAMPP\htdocs\node_modules\tapable\lib\HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), :22:1)
at Hook.CALL_ASYNC_DELEGATE [as _callAsync]   (E:\XAMPP\htdocs\node_modules\tapable\lib\Hook.js:18:14)
at run (E:\XAMPP\htdocs\node_modules\webpack\lib\Watching.js:88:33)
at E:\XAMPP\htdocs\node_modules\webpack\lib\Watching.js:83:6
at Compiler.readRecords (E:\XAMPP\htdocs\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compiler.js:894:11)
at run (E:\XAMPP\htdocs\node_modules\webpack\lib\Watching.js:79:26)

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! @ watch: `mix watch`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the @ watch script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

package.json

```
{
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
        "dev": "npm run development",
        "development": "mix",
        "watch": "mix watch",
        "watch-poll": "mix watch -- --watch-options-poll=1000",
        "hot": "mix watch --hot",
        "prod": "npm run production",
        "production": "mix --production"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "axios": "^0.21",
        "laravel-mix": "^6.0.18",
        "lodash": "^4.17.19",
        "postcss": "^8.2.12",
        "vue-loader": "^15.9.5",
        "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.12"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "vue": "^2.6.12",
        "vue-axios": "^3.2.4",
        "vue-router": "^3.5.1"
    }
}
```

PS E:\xampp\htdocs> npm install

npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@2.3.2 (node_modules\chokidar\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@2.3.2: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.13 (node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.13: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})

It was working before when I tried

npm cache clean --force

but now giving same error. I also tried

npm install webpack

It updated 1 package but still not working. I'm using win 10 64bit.

Deleted node_modules folder, reinstalled nodejs and npm. Nothing worked.

Don't want to delete package-lock.json. Thanks.

Comment: It would be helpful if you pasted the error as text, instead of an image link, so that people can find this post by searching by the error.

(Rock over London, rock on Chicago)

Answer (score 2):

I was facing this issue and was able to fix it by reinstalling node.js or run the node setup and choose repair, it seems that it's a problem related to npm itself